# Android TextView displays ATM text as trademark symbol when using GT Haptik font

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, fonts

This is a weird one, maybe someone ran into this --

Android's plain TextView displays any text string that ends with TM as a trademark symbol. As shown below, the text has no formatting, just plain TextView.

[image]

This happens *only* when I use the [GT Haptik font](http://gt-haptik.com/) but not otherwise: the default font shows plain ATM, as it should.

The TextView doesn't transform (c) or (r), only xxxTM.

Microsoft Office (see picture) doesn't do that, with the same exact font file.
[image]

Any suggestions how to prevent this?

Thank you!

Comment: It could be the font postprocessing doing that. Have you tested using spannableString instead of directly assigning text to the TextView?

Comment: Thanks @hetafoya. I had to educate myself on spannable.  Played around with it and didn't fix it for me. I did some more research and changed the original question -- all Android text widgets  do this, but nothing (as far as I can tell) that isn't Android!